# Count the photos!, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

CodeWars problem:

> *In a string we describe a road. There are cars that move to the right and we denote them with ">" and cars that move to the left and we
> denote them with "<". There are also cameras that are indicated by: "
> . ". A camera takes a photo of a car if it moves to the direction of
> the camera. Task Your task is to write a function such that, for the
> input string that represents a road as described, returns the total
> number of photos that were taken by the cameras. The complexity should
> be strictly O(N) in order to pass all the tests.*

Examples:

For ">>." -> 2 photos were taken

For ".>>" -> 0 photos were taken

For ">.<." -> 3 photos were taken

For ".><.>>.<<" -> 11 photos were taken

**I have a working code but it is too slow, so i can not pass the tests.**

My code:

```
def count_photos(road):
    x = 0
    for k,i in enumerate(road):
        if i == "<":
            x += road[:k].count(".")
        if i == ">":
            x += road[k:].count(".")
    return x
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: How would you solve the problem with pencil and paper? What is your understanding of the performance problem? (Hint: what does `.count` do?) Can you think of a way to get around that problem? (Hint: you are already looking at the input one symbol at a time. Can you think of a way that you could *already know* how many `.` have already been seen, by keeping track of them as you encounter them?)

Comment: For future reference, please read [ask], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. "I would appreciate any help, thanks." is [not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), which is why I have only given hints.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_photos(road):
photos = 0
left = 0
dot_founds = 0
for item in road:
    if item == ">":
        left += 1
    elif item == ".":
        photos += left
        dot_founds += 1
    elif item == "<":
        photos += dot_founds
    
return photos
```

Comment: Please format the code correctly and add some prose explaining how/why this solution works.